# Equivalent to csh $< in POSIX shell scripts

Tags: shell, sh, csh

I noticed a C shell script writeLog.csh for writing logs has the statement:

```
echo "date $<" >> $1
```

What does `$<` mean?

The c shell script is called in this context:

```
echo "The date is 20160111 " writeLog.csh record.log
```

That means that the script writeLog.csh would write "The date is 20160111" to the file record.log.

How do I do this with a shell script instead of c shell script?

Comment: This is not worth an answer, but `$<` can also be used in a makefile's suffix rule or pattern rule to refer to the file matched by the suffix/pattern. More info on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29#Suffix_rules) for example.

Answer (score 2):

`$<` reads a single line from standard input in the csh.

Assuming you mean a Posix shell, `read` is the equivalent command.

Your script would end up as:

```
read record
echo "date $record" >> $1
```

Example:

```
$ echo "The date is 20160111" | writelog.sh record.log
$ cat record.log
date The date is 20160111
```

But I think you will want to automatically timestamp the log records? In that case you'll want something like this:

```
read record
echo "`date`: $record" >> $1
```

This gives you records like so:

```
Mon Jan 11 21:38:58 CET 2016: The date is 2016011
```

Answer (score 0):

Google it.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/csh

$<

Substitutes a line from the standard input, with no further interpretation thereafter. It can be used to read from the keyboard in a shell script. (+) While csh always quotes $<, as if it were equivalent to '$<:q', tcsh does not. Furthermore, when tcsh is waiting for a line to be typed the user may type an interrupt to interrupt the sequence into which the line is to be substituted, but csh does not allow this.